# Cronyd service - NTP clients using OEL 8 NTP Server

Tags: ntp

We have an OEL 8  NTP Server. We have been using `chrony` service. we are trying find what clients are being served by the NTP server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chronyc sources
```

will describe the current time sources.

```
chronyc tracking
```

will describe the current clock.

See `chronyc help` and/or the manpages for `chronyc` for more information.